# How do you implement a login feature on a Wordpress site?

Tags: login, wp-login-form

How do you implement a login feature on a Wordpress site? I am wondering if Wordpress natively supports a login feature for the webpage itself. I am not talking about implementing a login page for the admin section, because it's already implemented, but a login page to be able to identify users across browsers and devices, since it would allow us to assign a custom user id for google analytics.

Is it possible to implement it without a plugin? And what tables can we use to define our users? Do we have to create our own tables for our own custom users?

Comment: Are you asking for something different than the `wp-login.php` screen? [How to log into WordPress](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how-to-login-to-wordpress/)

Comment: Yeah, I want to implement a login screen for users and not admins. The issue is that I don't know what the best practices are regarding implementing a login page using Wordpress. In Laravel, this is pretty straightforward, but not on Wordpress.

Comment: The login page for admins and for users in a vanilla WordPress website is the same. The thing that differentiates admins and non-admin users is [their Role](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/).

Comment: you're asking how to login without it going to WP Admin?

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to go to WP Admin. I just want users to be able to log in and have their account name displayed on the welcome page.

Answer (score 0):

Login is just a function that gets called in WordPress. Here is a shortcode plugin version for you. https://wordpress.org/plugins/login-sidebar-widget/

Comment: Hi, a question, do you need to manually create a user table?